# Vertically compare dates

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following data set:

> ```
>   ID          Start       End       
>   A         01JAN2015  31DEC2015     
>   A         01JAN2018  31DEC2018       
>   A         01JAN2019  31DEC2019         
>   A         01JAN2020  31DEC2020        
>   B         01JAN2015  31DEC2015      
>   B         01JAN2017  31DEC2017   
>   B         01JAN2018  31DEC2018
>   B         01JAN2020  31DEC2020
> ```

Is there a way to flag consecutive years (that must be subsequently analysed separately) to have the following output?

> ```
>   ID          Start       End       Flag    
>   A         01JAN2015  31DEC2015      0    
>   A         01JAN2018  31DEC2018      1      
>   A         01JAN2019  31DEC2019      1        
>   A         01JAN2020  31DEC2020      1       
>   B         01JAN2015  31DEC2015      0      
>   B         01JAN2017  31DEC2017      1  
>   B         01JAN2018  31DEC2018      1
>   B         01JAN2020  31DEC2020      0
> ```

When the years (records) are consecutive (it is sufficient to compare the year of the End of record (i) and record (i+1)) they must be flagged with 1 otherwise 0. I don't know how to "say" consecutive years to sas. I'm able to use lag function for horizontal comparisons but I don't know how to use it vertically.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Define "consecutive".  Do you mean that you want to test if lag(end)=(start - 1) ?

Comment: I do not understand your FLAG values. Why is it zero for the first observations of A but not for the first observation of B?

Comment: Exactly, because the jump does not occur always between the first and subsequent records. Sometimes, for some IDs first dates are consecutive while the last or the remaining are not. The jump is not always at the beginning.

Comment: Huh?  I still do not understand what you are trying to do.  For A there is one continuous period. For B there are three disjoint periods.  How does the FLAG variable you are proposing help to indicate that?

Comment: Sorry there was an error in "Desired output". For B, the disjoined periods will be flagged as 0 while the continuous will be flagged as 1. The same for A

Comment: Still does not make sense.  For B the fist record is zero since it is the first for B.  Then the second record starts a new period. Shouldn't that also be zero to indicate a new period has started?  Or is your flag just that the period consists of more than one observation? In which case shouldn't the first observation for A also be flagged with a one?

Comment: In a different way, I just need to subset consecutive years to merge between them. The use of a flag was an idea, not necessarily the best one

Comment: For B it is 0 because there is a jump after. In this case it is after because the first registration. sometimes it can be before as for its last record. Every time a record is by itself it will be 0 otherwise if it is possible to group periods because they are consecutive the flag should be 1

Comment: Still do not get it.  If you want to flag the LAST record in the period then you need to look ahead.  That is harder, but doable.  But probably not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect when a new period starts just compare to end of the previous observation.

```
data have ;
  input ID $ Start :date. End :date.;
  format start end date9.;
cards;
A 01JAN2015  31DEC2015
A 01JAN2016  31DEC2016
A 01JAN2017  31DEC2017
A 01JAN2018  31DEC2018
B 01JAN2015  31DEC2015
B 01JAN2017  31DEC2017
B 01JAN2018  31DEC2018
B 01JAN2020  31DEC2020
;

data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  new_period = (year(start)-1)>lag(year(end));
  if first.id then new_period=1;
run;
```

Result:

```
                                        new_
Obs    ID        Start          End    period

 1     A     01JAN2015    31DEC2015       1
 2     A     01JAN2016    31DEC2016       0
 3     A     01JAN2017    31DEC2017       0
 4     A     01JAN2018    31DEC2018       0
 5     B     01JAN2015    31DEC2015       1
 6     B     01JAN2017    31DEC2017       1
 7     B     01JAN2018    31DEC2018       0
 8     B     01JAN2020    31DEC2020       1
```

Or better just count the periods.

```
data better;
  set have;
  by id;
  period  + (year(start) - 1 ) > lag(year(end));
  if first.id then period=1;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    ID        Start          End    period

 1     A     01JAN2015    31DEC2015       1
 2     A     01JAN2016    31DEC2016       1
 3     A     01JAN2017    31DEC2017       1
 4     A     01JAN2018    31DEC2018       1
 5     B     01JAN2015    31DEC2015       1
 6     B     01JAN2017    31DEC2017       2
 7     B     01JAN2018    31DEC2018       2
 8     B     01JAN2020    31DEC2020       3
```